# Sharing a common background image in a UINavigationController hierarchy?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I know it's possible to set a background image for the UINavigationBar, but I would like to know if there is a way to share a common background view for all controllers in a UINavigationController. The idea is to have a UIImageView as the background that stays in place rather than "sliding" over itself when navigating to a new controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A navigation controller is a kind of view controller and it hosts the currently visible view controller by adding the VC view to its view. You can add things to that view too. Create your image view and add it as a subview of the nav controller view, then send it to the back (or insert at index 0).

Comment: Ah, of course. It does create a new problem with the way UINavigationController transitions in iOS7, though. :/

Comment: Depending on what you want you can also consider adding the image view to the window or adding a container view controller with the nav controller as a child.

Comment: What I mean is that the default transition no longer looks right. It assumes there is a background for each view that will "cover" the bits of the previous controller that are still on the screen. You can resolve this with a custom transition, though.